# Why is std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t() not constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, c++-chrono

The C++ standard (github.com/cplusplus/draft) has the `time_t` conversion functions (`std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t` and `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t`) for listed as `static` and `noexcept` but not `constexpr`.

Given that essentially all of the operations on `time_point` and `duration` are `constexpr` (including `duration_cast` and `time_point_cast`), I can't think of any reason to exclude them.  A quick inspection of the libstdc++ sources on my local machine confirms that these functions are implemented as simple duration/time_point casts.

Is there any reason that these two functions should not be `constexpr`?  Is this just a case of "because no one proposed they should be"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this just a case of "because no one proposed they should be"?

Yes, I think that is exactly right.

I'm curious:  Once you get a `constexpr time_t`, what are you going to do with it?  None of the C functions taking `time_t` are `constexpr`.

Comment: I have a timestamp class which previously used a `time_t` as the internal representation.  It currently offers a `constexpr` constructor from a `time_t`.  Now I'd like to change the internal representation to a `time_point`, but without `constexpr from_time_t` I'll be forced to remove `constexpr` from the `time_t` constructor which potentially breaks downstream user code.

Comment: @marack:  I see.  Yeah, that is frustrating.  I would be very tempted to just assume the common but unspecified epoch and representation and just roll your own constexpr conversion.  It is simple enough as you've already noted:  `system_clock::time_point(seconds(time_t_value));`.  You can also file a library defect report by following the instructions here:  http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue .